# Shiny DataTable: Save full data.frame with buttons extension

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am using DataTables with Shiny. With the buttons extension a user can download or print the data in the datatable. But only the visible part of the rows is downloaded/printed. I want to change that behaviour, so that the full data.frame with all rows can be downloaded. Is this possible with the buttons extension or do I have to switch to a downloadHandler?

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(a = 1:100, b = 1:100)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(df, 
                      extensions = c("Buttons"), 
                      options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                     buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
                      ))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would work if you use a `Scroller` :

```
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(df, 
                                      extensions = c('Buttons', 'Scroller'), 
                                      options = list(
                                        dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                        deferRender = TRUE,
                                        scrollY = 400,
                                        scroller = TRUE,
                                        buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
                                      ))
```

---

#### Edit

As commented by @Jav, this solution doesn't work when you have a large dataset. @Jav pointed out that using `server=FALSE` could be better a workaround, which allows you to use either the paging or scrolling mode:

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(df, server = FALSE,
                  extensions = c("Buttons"), 
                  options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                                 buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
                  ))
```

If you have a very large dataset that you don't want to fully load at first then you should implement Shiny's download handler.

Comment: Actually, this is not correct. Unless you have `server = FALSE`, It will still download only the part that is loaded in user-side. Of course, it is more than "visible rows" and thus in small datasets you might get a feeling that everything is being downloaded. But in big tables, you will see that it is only downloading a part.

Comment: 1) You can load whole table by scrolling through it and then using one of the buttons. But very silly in big tables. 2) use `server = FALSE` 3) use shiny download handler

Comment: If you use server=FALSE,when the data is big,it will be disconnect

Comment: Instead of a scroller, you can also give a page length option and allow users to show all data. 
`options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = c('pageLength', 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'),  pagelength = 10, lengthMenu = list(c(10, 25, 100, -1), c('10', '25', '100','All'))`