# Download Handler on RenderTable() dataframe in Shiny

Tags: r, download, widget, shiny

I have a shiny app that takes a csv file that looks like this:

```
category
action
```

and inputs it into the dataframe to filter the category with only "action".

Reproducible APP:

UI:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Actor Finder"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file","Upload Category List: Must have category as header"),
      selectInput("file4", "Select Type", c("A" = "A",
                                               "B" = "B",
                                               "C" = "C"), selected = "A"),
      numericInput("file5", "Choose cost", 1000000000),
      tags$hr()),    
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tb")
    )

  )
))
```

Server:

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
# use the below options code if you wish to increase the file input limit, in this example file input limit is increased from 5MB to 9MB
# options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 9*1024^2)

actor <- c('Matt Damon','George Clooney','Brad Pitt', 'Clive Owen', 'Morgan Freeman', 'Edward Norton', 'Adrian Granier')
category<-c('action', 'action', 'noir', 'action', 'thriller', 'noir', 'action')
movie <- c('Oceans Eleven', 'Oceans Twelve', 'Fight Club', 'Children of Men', 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'American History X', 'Entourage')
movies <- c(21, 23, 26, 12, 90, 14, 1)
cost <- c(210000, 2300000, 260000, 120000, 90000, 140000, 10000)
Type <- c('A','B','C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A')

moviedata<-data.frame(actor, category, movie, movies, cost, Type)

# This reactive function will take the inputs from UI.R and use them for read.table() to read the data from the file. It returns the dataset in the form of a dataframe.
# file$datapath -> gives the path of the file

shinyServer(function(input,output){
data <- reactive({
  file1 <- input$file
  if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
  read_csv(file=file1$datapath)

})


# this reactive output contains the summary of the dataset and display the summary in table format

# this reactive output contains the summary of the dataset and display the summary in table format
output$sum <- renderTable({
  if(is.null(data())){return ()}
  test<-subset(moviedata, category %in% data())
  test1<-filter(test, `Type`==input$file4)
  test1$`BUDGET`<-input$file5
  test1$CHECKING<-ifelse(test1$`BUDGET`>test1$cost,"YES", "NO")
  filter(test1, CHECKING=="YES")
})

 # the following renderUI is used to dynamically generate the tabsets when the file is loaded. Until the file is loaded, app will not show the tabset.
output$tb <- renderUI({
  if(is.null(data()))
    h5("Powered by", tags$img(src='optimatic.png'))
  else
    tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))
})

} 
)
```

I want to be able to do the following:

The output looks like this:

[image]

1) Add a download button to the renderTable dataframe. So let's say I change the filters for the new output in the UI, then I want to be able to download that new output.

2) Change the format of the dataframe to a dataTable from the DT package.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: For 1) I suggest storing the filtered data in a reactive() function or reactiveValues() with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042456/using-filtered-datatables-in-shiny. 2) You simply ask for the DT::renderDataTable() function?

Comment: I tried doing the DT::renderDataTable() but I got an error. Do I need to do anything else with that function besides adding the `DT::` in front of `renderDataTable()`? Also can you please provide a reproducible answer so I can test it out. I am very much new to this. Also if anything, the most important answer out of this is to figure out the download button. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Hi @Nick, then I guess you forgot to adapt the code on ui side. Did you change it to dataTableOutput()? Reproducible makes sense as soon as he problem is clear :).

Comment: I did not, I kept it as `uiOutput`. Should I change it to that? I haven't really changed anything from the code above yet. @TonioLiebrand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy to use DT:

1 - load the package:

```
library(DT)
```

2- render your table by replacing `renderTable` with `renderDataTable` (specifying `exptension` argument to include download button):

```
output$sum <- renderTable({...}, 
  extensions = c('Buttons'), 
  options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
  ))
```

3- output the result using `dataTableOutput` instead of `tableOutput` in the renderUI:

```
tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Summary", dataTableOutput("sum")))
```

Comment: I am realizing when I do the extension argument for downloads it only downloads my current display. So if the data is more than 10 rows it will download the first 10 rows rather than the whole dataset

Comment: I proposed an answer to that question there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729259/shiny-datatable-save-full-data-frame-with-buttons-extension/41729600#41729600